# How decode value from json?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried everything, but I cannot get it to work.
I need decode data from cp1361 to utf-8. Below is the used code:

```
import json
import request

path = 'result.json'

with open(path, 'r') as f:
  data = json.loads(f.read())
  for i in data['data']:
    a= i['CitySender'].encode()
    print(a.decode('utf-8'))
```

results.json

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "Number": "",
        "Redelivery": 0,
        "RedeliverySum": 0,
        "RedeliveryNum": "",
        "RedeliveryPayer": "",
        "OwnerDocumentType": "",
        "LastCreatedOnTheBasisDocumentType": "",
        "LastCreatedOnTheBasisPayerType": "",
        "LastCreatedOnTheBasisDateTime": "",
        "LastTransactionStatusGM": "",
        "LastTransactionDateTimeGM": "",
        "DateCreated": "28-04-2020 18:22:12",
        "CheckWeight": 0,
        "SumBeforeCheckWeight": 0,
        "PayerType": "Sender",
        "RecipientFullName": "",
        "RecipientDateTime": "04.05.2020 18:53:33",
        "ScheduledDeliveryDate": "02-05-2020 12:00:00",
        "PaymentMethod": "Cash",
        "CargoDescriptionString": "",
        "CargoType": "Parcel",
        "CitySender": "\\u041a\\u0438\\u0457\\u0432",
        "CityRecipient": "\\u041a\\u0438\\u0457\\u0432",
        "WarehouseRecipient": "",
        "CounterpartyType": "PrivatePerson",
        "AfterpaymentOnGoodsCost": 0,
        "ServiceType": "WarehouseWarehouse",
        "UndeliveryReasonsSubtypeDescription": "",
        "WarehouseRecipientNumber": 1,
        "LastCreatedOnTheBasisNumber": "",
        "PhoneRecipient": "",
        "RecipientFullNameEW": "",
        "MarketplacePartnerToken": "",
        "ClientBarcode": "",
        "RecipientAddress": "",
        "CounterpartyRecipientDescription": "\\u041f\\u0440\\u0438\\u0432\\u0430\\u0442\\u043d\\u0430 \\u043e\\u0441\\u043e\\u0431\\u0430",
        "CounterpartySenderType": "PrivatePerson",
        "DateScan": "0001-01-01 00:00:00",
        "PaymentStatus": "",
        "PaymentStatusDate": "",
        "AmountToPay": "",
        "AmountPaid": "",
        "LastAmountTransferGM": "",
        "LastAmountReceivedCommissionGM": "",
        "DocumentCost": 60,
        "DocumentWeight": 2,
        "AnnouncedPrice": 200,
        "UndeliveryReasonsDate": "",
        "RedeliveryPaymentCardDescription": "",
        "OwnerDocumentNumber": "",
        "InternationalDeliveryType": "",
        "WarehouseSender": "",
        "DeliveryTimeframe": "",
        "VolumeWeight": "2.00",
        "SeatsAmount": "1",
        "ActualDeliveryDate": "2020-04-30 14:36:41",
        "CardMaskedNumber": "",
        "BarcodeRedBox": "",
        "Packaging": [
            {
                "Description": "\\u041a\\u043e\\u0440\\u043e\\u0431\\u043a\\u0430 (2 \\u043a\\u0433)"
            }
        ],
        "AviaDelivery": 0,
        "OnlineCreditStatus": "",
        "AdjustedDate": "",
        "FreeShipping": 0,
        "CheckWeightMethod": "",
        "Status": "\\u0412\\u0456\\u0434\\u043f\\u0440\\u0430\\u0432\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u043d\\u044f \\u043e\\u0442\\u0440\\u0438\\u043c\\u0430\\u043d\\u043e",
        "StatusCode": "9",
        "DatePayedKeeping": "",
        "OnlineCreditStatusCode": ""
    }
],
"errors": [],
"warnings": [],
"info": [],
"messageCodes": [],
"errorCodes": [],
"warningCodes": [],
"infoCodes": []
```

}

the string that I am decoding :

```
\\u041a\\u0438\\u0457\\u0432
```

result:

```
\u041a\u0438\u0457\u0432
```

I get the string in CP1361 :(

in another sketch I tried this code :

```
from sys import getdefaultencoding
getdefaultencoding()  # utf-8
data = '\u041a\u0438\u0457\u0432'.encode()
print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

result:

```
Київ
```

I get the right result. I think that I need double decode, but I am not sure.

Comment: `.encode('cp1361').decode('cp1361').encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')` doesn't make any sense. And BTW your assumption about our sexual orientation might not be true for everyone.

Comment: sorry, there were some errors. I corrected the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i have tested this with your json file this should work:

```
def decodejohab(s):
    return str(s.encode("utf-8"), "unicode_escape")

import json
import request

path = 'result.json'

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    jsonfile = json.loads(f.read())
    for i, v in enumerate(jsonfile["data"]):
        print(decodejohab(jsonfile["data"][i]["CitySender"]))
```

Comment: it works. thanks. its my error , library is "requests"

Comment: so i wasnt sure about that :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
x = "\\u0412\\u0456\\u0434\\u043f\\u0440\\u0430\\u0432\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u043d\\u044f \\u043e\\u0442\\u0440\\u0438\\u043c\\u0430\\u043d\\u043e"
x.encode('utf_8').decode('unicode_escape')    
#'Відправлення отримано'
```